# What is the notation for procedural exponentiation?

Tags: summation, exponentiation, products

$\sum_{n=0}^{k}f(n)$ is the notation for $f(0)+f(1)+f(2)+...f(k)$

$\prod_{n=0}^{k}f(n)$ is the notation for $f(0)\cdot f(1)\cdot f(2)\cdot ...f(k)$.

What would the notation be to describe this
$f(k)^{f(k-1)^{f(k-2)...^{f(0)}}}$ be?

Comment: You may want to look into [tetration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration). The point is, even the case where the $f(i)$'s are constant is somewhat niche and obscure, so I doubt there is a consistent notation across the literature for this concept.

Comment: @MonstrousMoonshiner so I could just honestly make one up? I need it for a project

Comment: How about $$\uparrow_{n=0}^kf(n)$$

Comment: @GerryMyerson I'll call it myerson notation, I was just gonna use an uppercase e 

Comment: @script8man That might be a little hasty, I would suggest asking your teacher or advisor about it before you go ahead and do something like that.